# Getting max value from an arraylist of objects

Tags: java

I have an arraylist called cities with objects City from another class, and this object contains both the name of said city but also population. In one method I wanna sum all city populations, aka get the population of the country, however I'm getting an exception in .parseLong method the way I'm doing it. In another one, I wanna check what city has the largest population, but I'm not getting anything when I print and don't know how to fix it. Basically I don't know how to get the value of the objects inside the arraylist. Commented where I have issues for better understanding.  Help's appreciated!

```
public class Country {
    private String name;
    private City capital;
    private int pop;
    private ArrayList<City> cities;

    public Country(String name, Cidade capital, int pop) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
        this.pop = pop;
        cities = new ArrayList<>();
        cities.add(capital);
    }
    public long getTotalPop(){
        String c = null;
        Iterator<City> iter = cities.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            c += iter.next();
            long s = Long.parseLong(c); //giving exception here
            System.out.println(s);
            return s;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    public City getLargest(){
        for(City city: cities){
            if(city.getPop()>city.getPop()){ //method is fine but if is very wrong since am not sure what to compare to
                return city;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private int pop;

    public City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public City(String name, int pop) {
        this.name = nome;
        this.pop = pop;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPop() {
        return pop;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPop(int pop) {
        this.pop = pop;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I suspect the error says something to the effect of "`parseLong` expected a `String` but got a `City`", which it's saying because [`parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) expects a `String` but you've given it a `City`. I don't know what you expect from an answerer on here, given that the error message tells you precisely what's wrong.

Comment: Share you City class

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sorry if I wasn't clear. I know the issue. I just don't know of a way to evaluate the values inside the array of objects, and the issue happens in both the methods I listed, albeit in different ways. And I had also tried converting c to to a string and convert that string into a long using toString() and parseLong() but the exception was exactly the same  and says the following:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nullpaises.Cidade@682a0b20"

Comment: @DevilsHnd thanks for the help, but unfortunately neither work still :/ In the first method I can't use the getPop method since iter isn't an object of the class and in the second one It is only giving out the capital city when I test it

Comment: Tried that now but it's the same, and I also used a print method I created and all the cities I add are in there but when I use the getLargest() method it always prints whatever city I set as capital when creating the country class object

Comment: Do you realize that in order to sum up `int` values you don't need to turn them into a `String`? And there's no need in parsing it to `long`. Declare the variable for accumulating the total as `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About your Methode getTotalPop()

1. c should be a long variable and in initialized to 0 because now you are trying to increment a string which is impossible.
2. you are iterating about a list of cities so iter.next() will give you a city but you want the population of this city so call c += iter.next().getPop();
3. You don't have to use an iterator. It is okay but you won't get a benefit in this case. My recommendation use a enhanced for/foreach loop.

So use this(iterator):

```
public long getTotalPop(){
    long result = 0;
    Iterator<City> iter = cities.iterator();
    
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        result += iter.next().getPop();
    }
    return result;
}
```

or this(enhanced for/foreach loop):

```
public long getTotalPop(){
    long result = 0;
    
    for (City city : cities) {
        result += city.getPop();
    }
    return result;
}
```

### About your Methode getLargest()

There are some ways to do the job you could use an variable largest pop initialized to 0 and compare each City population with this variable and set it to the pop if it is greater. Or set your pop of the first City as the value to be compared.

With first City:

```
public City getLargest() {
    if (!cities.isEmpty()) {
        City largest = cities.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < cities.size(); i++) {
            City city = cities.get(i);
            if (largest.getPop() < city.getPop()) {
                largest = city;
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Furthermore because you don't initialize cities in the construtor other than to the new ArrayList don't do that in the constructor but like this:

```
private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();

public Country(String name, City capital, int pop) {
    this.name = name;
    this.capital = capital;
    this.pop = pop;
    this.cities.add(capital);
}
```

At last why is the pop of the country not the same as the pop of all of the cities it has? It would make totaly sense to initialize pop to the result of getTotalPop()

Comment: thanks for the explanation, understood everything really well! as for why the country isn't the pop, I probably explained it wrong, I want getTotalPop to get the pop of every city in the array, but not all cities of the country will be listed there, if I wanted pop of country I can just set a simple getter. Thanks again for the help and explanation!!